# A symmetric matrix is equal to the sum product of its eigenvalues, eigenvectors and transposed eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

> Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix and let $\{(\lambda_i, u_i)\}^n$ be its eigenpairs. Assume all eigenvectors are normalized. Prove that $$A = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i u_i u_i^T$$

---

I am stuck on this problem. I think I am missing an important proof or definition. First, I set $u_i u_i^T = 1$ since symmetric matrices have an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors, which is orthogonal by definition. So now:

$$ A = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i $$

I also know that I can define a matrix $D$ which is a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues of A in the entries on the main diagonal,  $A = P D P^{-1}$ which has a trace tr(**PDP$^-$$^1$**)=tr(**DP$^-$$^1$P**)=tr(**D**)=$\sum_{i=i}^n \lambda_i$. Unfortunately it is here that I am stuck since I do not believe that I can apply the trace operation to only one side of the equation. Any assistance is most appreciated.

Comment: I think $u_iu_i^T$ is not a scalar: it is a $n\times n$ matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$u_i^Tu_i$ is indeed $1$, but $u_iu_i^T$ is an $n\times n$-matrix.

A hint for the proof: $u_i$ is an orthonormal basis, and a matrix is determined by how it acts on basis vectors. What happens if you multiply $\sum\limits_i \lambda_i u_i u_i^T$ and $u_j$ for some $j$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $$A u_i= \lambda_i u_i~~~(1)$$ as the symmetric matrix has complete orthonormal eigenvectors $$\sum_{i}^n u_i u^T_i=I ~~~(2)$$ Multiply (1) by $u^T_i$ from the left  and sum over $i$, to get $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} A u_i u^T_i= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i u_i u^T_i ~~~~(3)$$ So from (2) it follows that
$$A=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i u_i u^T_i$$